# How to trigger jquery datepicker (www.keith-wood.name) from a hyperlink

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to show a calender when a user clicks on a link. Upon selecting the date I want to redirect to the same page with date selected appended as querystring.

I am using datepicker from http://keith-wood.name/datepickBasics.html and so far i have managed to do following.

```
    $('#checkup_date').datepick({
        alignment:'bottom',
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        onSelect:
                function(getDate, instance) {
                    window.location = "<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>?checkup_date=" + getDate;
                }           ,
        yearRange: '<?php echo date("Y") - 100; ?>:<?php echo date("Y"); ?>'
    });
```

once I click on this is the url which is there after redirection
http://www.mywebsite.com/panels/records/consultations_view.php?checkup_date=Tue Apr 30 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

whereas i want the date as http://www.mywebsite.com/panels/records/consultations_view.php?checkup_date=2013-04-30

Please help achieving this or if you know a better a way to trigger a calendar from a hyperlink using the same plugin.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a [**trigger**](http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html#showTrigger)  by giving the ID (hyperlink elements ID).

> The element(s) that will trigger a popup datepicker to appear when they are clicked.

```
$(selector).datepick({showTrigger: 
    '<img src="img/calendar.gif" alt="Popup" class="trigger">'}); 
$(selector).datepick({showTrigger: '#myicon'});
```

Comment: But how will I redirect to a url along with date as querystring and also in YYYY-MM-DD format. If you can help me with that, that will solve my issue. Please let me know.

Comment: if you see http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html#onSelect you will get the date  from var date = dates[0];  so pass that as query parameter

Comment: Glad to help you.Please upvote and mark it as answer.if its helpful.

Comment: @Asnexplore never got around to accepting this answer? How rude.